# Remove files newer than X day and hour

Tags: files, rm, timestamps

I want to remove files, more specifically, symbolic links of /usr/include that are newer than 2 JUN 22:27

How can I do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You might want to use `find -newermt`.

Make sure to review files to be removed first:

```
find /usr/include -type l -newermt "Jun 2 22:27"
```

Use `-delete` to perform actual removes.

```
find /usr/include -type l -newermt "Jun 2 22:27" -delete
```

Comment: Extra info, delete normal files from current directory, example: `find . -newermt "Aug 3 5:27" -delete`

Comment: `-type l` didn't work instead I used `-type f`

Answer (score -1):

I know the most voted solution may work for alott of people but it did not for me.
I had to do it with unix timestamp.

```
 find . -type f -newermt "$(date -d @1494500000)" -delete
```

You can convert the timestamp easily with a unix timestamp converter.

Comment: Your answer could be useful but it seams not to be working, it returns: "find: I cannot figure out how to interpret ‘Tue Oct 10 07:00:00 AM +07 2023’ as a date or time"